# Is it possible to declare a variable in a conditional statement outside of it?

Tags: java, variables, printing

Im quite new to programming and just started to build some simple projects. Im having a bit of a problem debugging what exactly is going wrong. Or I might have an idea on it.

```
if (operator == "+") {
      int result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    } else if (operator == "-") {
      int result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    } else if (operator == "/") {
      int result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    } else if (operator == "*") {
      int result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    } else {
      String result = "The operator you entered doesn't seem to be valid.\n Please try either of these operators: +, -, /, *";
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Here, Im getting the error, ***"./Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(result);
^
symbol:   variable result
location: class Main'"***

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Declare the variable outside the `if`. But with the current design, this will not work since `result` has different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to declare a variable in a conditional statement outside of it?

Of course it is.  You declare `result` (once) *before* the if statement(s) and make sure that all of the "cases" assign a value to it.  Then you can use `result` at the end.

But you have to decide on a single type for `result`.  In your example you cannot make up your mind if it is `int` or `String`.  It has to be one or the other.  The type *cannot* depend on the value of `operator`:   it has to be static<sup>1</sup>.

You could:

- convert the result of the arithmetic to a `String`; e.g.

  ```
   result = Integer.toString(firstNumber + secondNumber);
  ```
- you could have two variables; e.g. `int result;` and `String error`
- you could declare a custom class that will hold either a number or an error message,
- and so on.

<sup>(Though Java doesn't support variables whose type is dynamic, some other language do.  But even in languages that support dynamic types, this kind of thing should generally be avoided, as it tends to make the code more complicated and harder to understand.  Your example is too trivial for this to apply.)</sup>

---

But there is another major error in your code:

```
if (operator == "+")   // MISTAKE!!!
```

Comparing strings using `==` will often (typically) give the wrong result; see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832)

---

<sup>1 - Static as in "static typing", not `static` in the Java sense.</sup>

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. `if (operator.equals("+")) {
      String result = Integer.toString(firstNumber + secondNumber);
    } else if (operator.equals("-")) {
      String result = Integer.toString(firstNumber - secondNumber);
    } else if (operator.equals("/")) {
      String result = Integer.toString(firstNumber / secondNumber);
    } else if (operator.equals("*")) {
      String result = Integer.toString(firstNumber * secondNumber);
    } else {
      String result = "text";
    }

    System.out.println(result);`

Comment: @RownokHasan why do you declare another result variable before the call to println? Just delete the 2nd last line.

Comment: @RownokHasan - As I said, "You declare `result` **once** ...".  (Perhaps you didn't read / understand the first part of my answer??)